# In Cypress 10, how can we check whether elements in drop-down are sorted alphabetically or numerically?

Tags: sorting, cypress

[image]*****I need to know all these listed data are sorted by XXXX digit number****

Comment: Please add the code you tried along with the html.

Comment: <input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" id="organizationId" placeholder="Tout" type="text" class="MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-input MuiInputBase-inputSizeSmall MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd MuiAutocomplete-input MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused css-sqq937" aria-autocomplete="list" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" value="17621 - Alberta Motor Association Insurance Company">

Answer (score 1):

The steps to do this are

1. get the option elements
2. extract the text as an array
3. slice off the number part
4. compare members to sorted version

```js
cy.get('.MuiAutocomplete-root').click()          // open the options list

cy.get('.MuiAutocomplete-option')                
  .should('have.length.gt', 1)                   // wait for loading options
  .then($options => {                            // 1. get the option elements

    const texts = [...$options].map(option => option.innerText)        // 2. extract the text as an array  
    const numbers = texts.map((text) => +(text.split('-')[0].trim()))  // 3. slice off the number part

    expect(numbers).to.have.ordered.members([...numbers].sort())       // 4. compare members 
                                                                       // to sorted version
  })
```

---

#### Don't use .sort()

This gives you the wrong answer, for example

```js
const strings =['b', 'a', 'c']
cy.wrap(strings).should('equal', strings.sort())  // passes, but it's not sorted!
```

because `strings.sort()` changes the original array and then compares it to itself, so will always pass even when original list is not sorted.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `chai-sorted` library to avoid complexity and errors.

**Install**

```js
npm install chai-sorted

or

yarn add -D chai-sorted
```

**The test is**

```js
chai.use(require("chai-sorted"))

cy.get('.MuiAutocomplete-option')                
  .should('have.length.gt', 1)                 
  .then($options => [...$options].map(option => option.innerText))
  .should('be.sorted')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Since I am not sure about the selector for the dropdown list item, I am adding just a placeholder `selector`, and edit that with a valid selector.

You can use `sort()` if you are operating on different arrays, that's what I have done here. We are creating two same sets of arrays here `strings_orig` and `strings_will_apply_sort`. We are keeping `strings_orig` unchanged where we are using the `sort()` for `strings_will_apply_sort`. And then finally we are comparing both of them.

```js
cy.get('selector').then(($elements) => {
  var strings_orig = $elements.map(($el) => $el.text())
  var strings_will_apply_sort = $elements.map(($el) => $el.text())
  expect(strings_orig).to.equal(strings_will_apply_sort.sort())
})
```